# Copy & Paste with Microsoft Office

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-access

I have 300 rows of data in a table with a single column ( Excel, Access or Word-table doesn't matter) and I want to resize it for printing. So the data will have size 25x12 instead of 300x1. Is there any copy & paste option that lets me do that?

I don't want to do it in 12 steps, selecting 50 each time. Since I have to do it for 32000 rows over all, which would result in over 1000 copy pasts.

Comment: No it is not possible the way you want to do it. I'd automate it with an Excel macro or something.

Answer (score 0):

Printing a Single Column in Multiple Columns http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T002219_Printing_a_Single_Column_in_Multiple_Columns.html

also with what I said before (below), this should solve the multipart problem. The question has nothing to with copying and pasting.

In Excel 2007 , There is a DataTab->GetExternal Data , That would import the data to Excel, From Excel you can format it all anyway you like for printing , to reload all you need is to press Refresh. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: ok i have the data in Excel, Word, Access and I'm happy with any way and programm to resize the data to a  table in Word, a Excel Woorksheet .... with the size 25x12 (Office 2007)

Comment: I would be able to install 2010 if that makes the problem easier.

Comment: @eactor : In Excel 2007 , There is a DataTab->GetExternal Data , That would import the data to Excel, From Excel from excel you can format it anyway you like, to reload all you need is to press Refresh. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I tried a few, but no improvement. I'm not able to reduce the number of rows of the source with it

Comment: @eactor : I don't follow what you mean. You can import all the rows to excel and then filter them any way you like, what is the problem?

Comment: sry, I german, i try to explain what I really meant. I have a source with a lot of rows and for a book register I want them in a table. 1-100 first column 101-200 in column two and so on. For that reason I have to split the rows in more then on column and not just like those examples with first and last name. Hopefully that helps

Comment: The question is something else entirely. we know how to move all the data into excel in one go. Now you want to tranfrom the from a single column layout to two, multiple column layout. The question is why? for printing purposes? And now the question has nothing to do with copy and pasting, since all the data is a table in excel a different question is how to move a table into multi column format,That is a different question than the original question about how not to copy and paste 1000 times. This question is answered, ask a separte question about how to format a table into columns.

Comment: @Arjang, with all the additional comments I also read @eactor's question as wanting to reshape an array with Office. So I don't think your answer really answered his problem, even before the comments. But if you think it's not possible, feel free to answer that.

Comment: Or [have a look at this article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29239907/reshape-array-of-numbers.aspx) and let him use your method of loading the data, then this to reshape the index through referencing to cells on another worksheet